# Find the volume of the bounded region

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The question is the following：

> Let $p,q \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and let $f$ be the surface given by $4px=y^2+z^2$. Find the volume of the region between $f$ and the plane $x = q$.

My attempt is the following:

The enclosed region is bounded above by $f$ and bounded below by the plane $x = q$. Thus
$$
q \leq x \leq \frac{y^2+z^2}{4p}
$$
Project the region into the $y$-$z$ plane and the region is represented by
$$
y^2+z^2 = 4pq \quad \implies \quad -\sqrt{4pq-y^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{4pq-y^2}
$$
and $y$ is bounded within the circle $-\sqrt{4pq} \leq y \leq \sqrt{4pq}$. Therefore, the volume of the enclosed region can be computed as
\begin{align*}
    V &= \int_{-\sqrt{4pq}}^{\sqrt{4pq}}\int_{-\sqrt{4pq-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4pq-y^2}}\int_h^{(y^2+z^2)/(4p)}\ dx\ dz\ dy \\
    &= \int_{-\sqrt{4pq}}^{\sqrt{4pq}}\int_{-\sqrt{4pq-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4pq-y^2}}\frac{y^2+z^2}{4p}-q \ dz\ dy  \\
    &= \int_{-\sqrt{4pq}}^{\sqrt{4pq}}\frac{y^2}{4p}z+\frac{1}{12p}z^3-hz \Bigg|_{-\sqrt{4pq-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4pq-y^2}} \ dy \\
    &= \int_{-\sqrt{4pq}}^{\sqrt{4pq}} 2\left(\frac{y^2}{4p}-q\right)\cdot\sqrt{4pq-y^2}-\frac{1}{12p}\left(2\sqrt{4pq-y^2}\right)^3\ dy\\
    &= 
\end{align*}
and I have no idea how to evaluate the last integral. Did I do something wrong here? Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few mistakes. The bound of $x$ should be the other way round,

$\frac{y^2+z^2}{4p} \leq x \leq q$. Also in the last step, it is not $\left(2 \sqrt{4pq-y^2}\right)^3$, rather $2 \left(\sqrt{4pq-y^2}\right)^3$ .

If you fix all of that the integrand in the last step boils downs to the form $(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}$ which is not straightforward either.

On the other hand, it is much easier to solve it using cylindrical coordinates, $y^2 + z^2 = r^2$

So $\displaystyle \frac{r^2}{4p} \leq x \leq q, 0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{4pq}, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

So the volume integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{4pq}} \int_{r^2/(4p)}^q r \ dx \ dr \ d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{4pq}} r(q - \frac{r^2}{4p}) \ dr \ d\theta = 2\pi pq^2$